# Why am I getting the error "db_name must be a string or symbol"?

Tags: mongodb, sinatra, mongoid, yaml

**Quick version (for those familiar with [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/) & [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/))**: If it's *not* the [Psyche](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych)/[Syck](http://rubyforge.org/projects/syck/) YAML-parsing issue, why *else* might I get this error when trying to connect to a MongoDB database using Mongoid? (Or maybe it *is* that issue, in which case, how do I fix my mongoid.yml file, posted below?)

---

**More detailed (original) version**:

I have a Sinatra app interacting with a MongoDB database via Mongoid:

```
configure do
    Mongoid.load!('config/mongoid.yml')
end
```

And my mongoid.yml file looks like this:

```
development:
    host: localhost
    database: project_development

test:
    host: localhost
    database: project_test

production:
    uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>
```

Whenever I try to interact with the database in some way, I get the error **db_name must be a string or symbol**.

Now, I have found *plenty* of information on Google about this; but everything I can find seems to indicate that the problem has to do with Ruby now using the Psyche YAML parser instead of the old Syck parser. I don't think that's actually relevant in my case because, as far as I can tell, the above YAML should be perfectly parsable by either.

(For what it's worth, though, I *have* tried using the `YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'` trick, to no avail. I got the exact same error message.)

When I change the configuration to this:

```
Mongoid.configure do |config|
    name = "project_development"
    host = "localhost"
    config.master = Mongo::Connection.new.db(name)
end
```

...then everything works fine. So I know that MongoDB is working on my machine. It's specifically when I use a YAML file that things go awry.

So what gives?

Comment: Did you make sure `ENV['RACK_ENV']` is set properly, as that is what `Mongoid.load!` uses if it doesn't find `Rails.env`

Comment: @Rubish: I tried using `set :environment, :development` using Sinatra; that should've done it, right?

Comment: @Rubish: Wow, color me stunned! I changed my code from `set :environment` to setting `ENV['RACK_ENV']` explicitly, and it worked! How about you turn that comment into an answer, so you can get some rep points? ;)

Comment: Call me hungry for rep, BTW I have never worked with sinatra.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure that `ENV['RACK_ENV']` is set properly, as that is what `Mongoid.load!` uses if it doesn't find `Rails.env`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with rails and solved it in this way :

The Problem lies in the different expectations of Mongoid and MongodbLogger concerning the structure of the mongoid.yml.
Short : just add the database in addition on the upper level :

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: apollo_development                       <<<< for the rest
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
  database: apollo_development                           <<<<main level for logger
    .... more stuff for the logger
```

The advantage is that you can use a database for your data and another for the logger.
Technical there are two independant systems using the yml : the logger and MongoId.